# ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental. C:\wamp\www\testjsgraphql\src\index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I install node js 10 in my machine but now when I test import package graphql in file .js I found this error:

> ```
>   $ node --experimental-modules src/index.js
> ```

```
    (node:14076) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
    C:\wamp\www\testjsgraphql\src\index.js:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {GraphQLSer
    ver} from "./graphql-yoga";
                                                                         ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
        at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
        at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
        at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:56:15)
        at setExecutor (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:50:23)
```

code indes.js

```
//import {GraphQLServer} from "graphql-yoga";
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')
import {Query} from "./resolvers/Query.mjs";
//définir le schèma du graphQL
//notre contrat ce que nous offrons à travers notre serveur graphQL
const typeDefs = "src/schema/schema.graphql";

//l'implémentation de notre contrat
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
  },
};

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.start(() => console.log('test Server is running on localhost:4000'));
```

code package.json:

```
{
"name": "testjsgraphql",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon -e js,mjs,json,graphql src/index.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "graphql-yoga": "^1.18.3",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
},
"type": "module"
```

}

I add "type":"module" but also error and I launch node --experimental-modules src/index.js but also error

how to fix error please